# How to add new data in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my logic for adding new person in firebase realtime databse. But instead of making a new entry it is just updating the old data with new one.

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            /*
            new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL)
                    .push()
                    .child("title")
                    .setValue(text.getText().toString());
            */

            Firebase ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String address = editTextAddress.getText().toString().trim();

            //Creating Person object
            Person person = new Person();

            //Adding values
            person.setName(name);
            person.setAddress(address);
            ref.child("Person").setValue(person);

        }
    });


    new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                //Getting the data from snapshot
                Person person = postSnapshot.getValue(Person.class);

                //Adding it to a string
                String string = "Name: "+person.getName()+"\nAddress: "+person.getAddress()+"\n\n";

                //Displaying it on textview
                textViewPersons.setText(string);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

What is wrong here? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Go through the new Firebase docs, you are using the old API's

Comment: have look on this may be it help you :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338409/rerofit-firebase/37338410#37338410

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath New firebase docs are not helpful at all. Those docs are meant for high level experts in firebase, they are not for people who are new to it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are using always the **same ref**

```
 Person person = new Person();
 //Adding values
 person.setName(name);
 person.setAddress(address);
 ref.child("Person").setValue(person);
```

[Check the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data#basic_write):

> Using setValue() in this way overwrites data at the specified location, including any child nodes.

In your case you **are overriding the same data** for this reason.

You should use the `push()` method to generate a unique ID every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference.

```
 Person person = new Person();
 //Adding values
 person.setName(name);
 person.setAddress(address);
 DatabaseReference newRef = ref.child("Person").push();
 newRef.setValue(person);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. adding part is working now as expected. Can you please help me on what changes i should made in onDataChange so it display all the persons added in database.

Comment: You can use the onChildAdded() callback using the ref.child("Person") as reference.

Answer (score 2):

every time when you optate to insert data to database call the follwing method.
You can integrate as many attributes you optate.It will engender a unique key everytime and insert records.

```
 public void insert2database(double latitude,double longitude,String name) {

    HashMap<String,String> student=new HashMap<>();
    
    student.put("Name",name);
    student.put("Lat", String.valueOf(latitude));  
    student.put("Long", String.valueOf(longitude));   
    student.put("Phone", String.valueOf("78787500000")); 
    
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference tasksRef = rootRef.child("USERS").push();
    tasksRef.setValue(student);
}
```

It will be in the database hierarchy like this

```
-database-4df17-default-rtdb
   -USERS
      -MUqgUu8zUpYcIaUVSsj
        -Lat:  "25.9405145"
        -Long: "79.9100086"
        -Name:"Dilroop"
        -Phone: "78787500000"
      -MUqoL2AUQFjH2ggKWev
        -Lat: "32.9405145"
        -Long: "73.9178186"
        -Name: "Sanghavi"
        -Phone: "78787500000"
      -MUsfc-H-7KdQhrkHb_F
        -Lat: "52.9405145"
        -Long: "79.9175856"
        -Name: "MDNSRF"
        -Phone: "78787500000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new Child to your data, such as:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUid();
Firebase rootRef = new Firebase(Config.USER_URL);
Firebase userRef = rootRef.child("Users");
Person newUser = new Person();
newUser.setFirstName(firstName);
newUser.setLastName(lastName);
userRef.child(userId).setValue(newUser);
```

The userId varies when the logging user is different, therefore, you will always go to a new data list for a new logged-in-user in the userId under Users.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to the `"Person"` child and setting it's value (`setValue()`) every time you click `buttonSave`, which only edits that one child.  Try to use [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data) instead.