# android - get string from edittext and store it in array

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a

EditText- `addArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextArea);`

and ArrayList - `public static ArrayList<String> areaList = new ArrayList<String>();`

and a Button- `addbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBTN);`

This is my code to Store Strings into array. It displaying the toastMessage but I doesn't know whether its storing Strings or not.

```
 addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String area = addArea.getText().toString();
                if (!area.isEmpty()){
                    areaList.add(area);
                    toastmessage(area+" added successfully.");
                    addArea.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
```

What is need is, The spinner is in the next layout. When I click the spinner it should diplay the items that i have enterd in the edittext.

Comment: you want return the `areaList` to `Spinner` ?

Comment: Yeah.. The spinner is in the next layout. When I click the spinner it should diplay the items that i have enterd in the edittext.

Comment: On your IDE editor, click to the left of `toastmessage(area+" added successfully.");` line on the margin to add a breakpoint (red dot appears). Next, run your application in Debug mode (Run > Debug). When the button is clicked, the application will freeze and a window will show in your IDE, you can then see what elements are in `areaList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether the list is added, you can check by this way

```
 for (int i=0; i<areaList.size();i++){
        addArea.append(areaList.get(i));
        addArea.append("\n");
    }
```

You can know whether the `string` is stored into the `areaList` by checking the `textView` setText value.

---

To pass the `areaList` to next Activity, add this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("areaList",areaList);
```

In the second `Activity`, use this line to get all the `areaList` data

```
ArrayList<String> areaList = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("areaList");
```

Then set the `areaList` to `spinner`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, areaList);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: im a beginner can you explian?

Comment: place the code below `toast` message and remove the  `.setText("")`, then you can see

Comment: sorry, is `areaList.get(i)`

Comment: It displaying the same String in EditText.

Comment: how to display that in the spinner?

Comment: sorry for the late rply... Your code works fine but it is storing items temporarily. When i close and open the app I should again enter the Strings. Is there any way to save the strings permanently?

Comment: You need to store them inside database.

Comment: I have firebase database... Can I store Strings in that?

Comment: Sure you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561497/how-to-add-new-data-in-firebase-android

Comment: I never use firebase . I only know SQLite.

Comment: You need to insert into firebase, then in the next activity, retrieve data from firebase and set to spinner.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see make sure the item is added you can print the `array` or check its `size`.
First declare a global variable as `int lastSize;`

```
lastSize = 0; //we start from 0
addbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String area = addArea.getText().toString();
                if (!area.isEmpty()){
                    areaList.add(area);
                    //size has changed, means new item added successfully
                    if (areaList.size() > lastSize) {
                       toastmessage(area+" added successfully.");
                       addArea.setText("");
                    }
                    //lets update lastSize to record latest size
                    lastSize = areaList.size();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: how to print the array?

Comment: @John Joe have given example of printing the array in another answer.

Comment: Im a beginner and honestly I don't know how to implement that method.. Can u help me? So i can learn!!

Comment: @Spidey I have updated the code to check for the changes, this should help