# android: checkbox usage in fragment which contains recycler view

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

In my app about health, there is a fragment in which doctor can add or deny patient to his/her own patient list. I use a `recyclerView` to show all patients, in each items there are informations about patiens like names, birthday, city and a `checkBox` which shows patient is added or not. Top of the page there is another `checkBox` to select all patients, also there are add and deny `textViews`. I want to use these `textViews` to add or deny patients which is selected of their own `checkBoxes`. After click add `textView` patients will add to Firebase Database. I could not do that features.How can i do? Here is my codes:

```
public class FragmentHastaBasvurulari extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<String> hastaAdi=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> hastaOzellikleri=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> hastaliklar=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> hastaOnayi=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Users> hastalar=new ArrayList<>();


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private RecyclerView rvHastaBasvuru;
  private CheckBox checkBoxHepsiniSec;

private TextView tvReddet,tvOnayla;


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("Hasta Başvuruları");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hasta_basvurulari, container, false);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef=database.getReference();
    rvHastaBasvuru=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvHastaBasvuru);
            checkBoxHepsiniSec=(CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHepsiniSec); 

    tvOnayla=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvOnayla);
    tvReddet=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReddet);



    myRef.child("kullanicilar")
            .child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("hastalar").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                EklenecekHasta eklenecekHasta = ds.getValue(EklenecekHasta.class);

                    DatabaseReference hastaRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("kullanicilar").child(eklenecekHasta.getUserId());
                    hastaRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Users hasta = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);

                                String sehir, dogumTarihi,hastaliklar1;

                                if(hasta.getSehir().equals("Seçiniz")){
                                    sehir="---";
                                } else {
                                    sehir=hasta.getSehir();
                                }
                                if(hasta.getDogumtarihi().equals("../../....")){
                                    dogumTarihi="---";
                                } else {
                                    dogumTarihi=hasta.getDogumtarihi();
                                }
                                if(hasta.getHastaliklar().equals("")){
                                    hastaliklar1="---";
                                } else {
                                    hastaliklar1=hasta.getHastaliklar();
                                }
                                hastaAdi.add(hasta.getAd()+" "+hasta.getSoyad());
                                hastaOzellikleri.add(hasta.getCinsiyet()+"  "+sehir+"  "+dogumTarihi);
                                hastaliklar.add(hastaliklar1);
                                hastaOnayi.add(hasta.getOnay());
                                hastalar.add(hasta);

                            }

                            rvHastaBasvuru.setAdapter(adapter);
                            rvHastaBasvuru.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        }
                    });

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }


        HastaListesiAdapter adapter= new HastaListesiAdapter(getContext(),hastaAdi,hastaOzellikleri,hastaliklar,hastaOnayi,hastalar);

    });



    tvOnayla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    tvReddet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });



    return view;
}
```

Here is my adapter class codes:

```
public class HastaListesiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HastaListesiAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private static final String TAG="HekimListesiAdapter";

private ArrayList<String> hastaAdi=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> hastaOzellikleri=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> hastaliklar=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> hastaOnayi=new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Users> hastalar=new ArrayList<>();
private Context myContext;


public HastaListesiAdapter(Context myContext, ArrayList<String> hastaAdi, ArrayList<String> hastaOzellikleri,
                           ArrayList<String> hastaliklar,ArrayList<String> hastaOnayi,ArrayList<Users> hastalar) {
    this.hastaAdi = hastaAdi;
    this.hastaOzellikleri = hastaOzellikleri;
    this.myContext = myContext;
    this.hastaliklar=hastaliklar;
    this.hastaOnayi=hastaOnayi;
    this.hastalar=hastalar;
}



@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {

    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hasta_item,parent,false);
    ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int i) {


    holder.itemHastaAd.setText(hastaAdi.get(i));
    holder.itemHastaOz.setText(hastaOzellikleri.get(i));
    holder.itemHastaliklar.setText(hastaliklar.get(i));

    //Hasta hekim tarafından onaylanmış mı onaylanmamış mı
    if(hastaOnayi.get(i).equals("evet")){
        holder.checkBoxHastaSec.setChecked(true);
    } else if(hastaOnayi.get(i).equals("hayır")){
        holder.checkBoxHastaSec.setChecked(false);
    }

    // CheckBox ın tıklanması üzerine yapılacak işlem

    holder.checkBoxHastaSec.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

            String secilimi;
            if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                secilimi="evet";
            } else {
                secilimi="hayır";
            }

        }



    });




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return hastaAdi.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView itemHastaAd,itemHastaOz,itemHastaliklar;
    CheckBox checkBoxHastaSec;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemHastaAd=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemHastaAd);
        itemHastaOz= itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemHastaOz);
        itemHastaliklar=itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemHastaliklar);
        checkBoxHastaSec=itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHastaSec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to replace your string arrayLists with one arrayList of your custom model and also you can have a boolean for representing data in your checkbox.for example create a model like this:

```
class YourModel()
{
  String hastaAdi;
  String hastaOzellikleri;
  //... another variables
  Boolean isAdded;

  //... set & get or other methods
}
```

now you should pass ArrayList to your adapter and set value for your recyclerView widgets by this arrayList. and then you can initialise or change checkBox value with your isAdded boolean.

Comment: Is IsAdded variable dynamic? because the doctor can remove the checkbox and choose again.

Comment: yes it can be changed, it is better to have a set method in your data model but for now, for changing the isAdded variable you just need to write something like this : yourModelArrayList.get(i).isAdded = true

Comment: ok, model is working, but how can i add selected patients to firebase database with click tvOnayla textView?

Comment: you should just insert data to firebase in onClickEvent of your textview.please check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561497/how-to-add-new-data-in-firebase-android

Comment: i know usage of firebase database, but in that case, do i need list which contains selected patients or another structure? i mean Is it possible to add a list to selected patients

Comment: if i got your mean , you want to send just selected patients to server. so you should have a function for example sendFilteredData() and create a temporary arrayList in this function, then you should have a for loop in this method and check if isAdded is true add the object to your temporary list. and at end you should send this list to firebase.

Comment: how can i add select all checkbox to select all items's checkboxes?