# Can i insert multiple values using same id without using push()? because if i use push() it is creating a unique key. so i dont need that

Tags: android, firebase

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("User");


                myRef.child(user).push().setValue(user);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).setValue(pgname);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("email").setValue(email);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("owner").setValue(owner);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("phone").setValue(phone);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("address").setValue(Address);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("pin").setValue(pin);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("fact").setValue(fact);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("rent").setValue(rent);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("sharing").setValue(s1);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("sharing").setValue(s2);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("sharing").setValue(s3);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("sharing").setValue(s12);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("sharing").setValue(s13);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("sharing").setValue(s23);
                myRef.child(user).child(pgname).child("sharing").setValue(s123);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a modal class for your entity . And set the values through it, by creating a single object of an id .

You need to use `push()` for the first time, and use  `setValue()` when need to update a value at a reference as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562715/7200713).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
String pushId = ref.push().getKey();
ref.child(pushId).child(pgname).setValue(pgname);
```

First, create a random id using `push()` and store it in a variable, then you can use it as a parent node of other child nodes.