# Android-Kotlin couldn't use set Value command

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Im trying to make a chatting app like messenger or something with kotlin. I don't know but setValue command isn't works here. I want to use setValue for writing uid,username and profile image to Firebase Database.
Here is the code

```
    private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(profileImageUrl: String){
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/$uid")

        val user = User(uid, username_edittext_register.text.toString(), profileImageUrl)

        ref.setValue(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d("MainActivity","Database'e ulaşıldı")

                    val intent = Intent (this, LatestMessagesActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.or(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
    }

}
class User(val uid: String,val username: String, val profileImageUrl: String)
```

And my implementations are ;

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The accepted answer for the linked post, which includes link to documentation, may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561497/how-to-add-new-data-in-firebase-android

Comment: Have you tried to attach onFailure listener to see if something's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting uid as hierarchy like database.child may this help you ,
becouse your code seems fine but reference may be not correct

```
private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

database = Firebase.database.reference
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
   val user = User(uid, username_edittext_register.text.toString(),profileImageUrl)
   
 database.child("users").child(uid).setValue(user)
```