# 'Person()' has private access in 'android.app.Person'

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to insert a new country into the database without using the push() function, but the data override them in the database. So I found to use Person class.

```
public class AddCountriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText country;
    Button insert;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_countries);
        insert = findViewById(R.id.insert);
        country = findViewById(R.id.country);
       
 insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadToFirebase();
            }
        });
}

 protected void uploadToFirebase(){
        String countrydb = country.getText().toString().trim();

        FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference root = db.getReference("Countries");
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName(countrydb);
        String s = "country";
        root.child(s).setValue(person);
}
}
```

But the error occur that is given below:

> 'Person()' has private access in 'android.app.Person'
> Cannot resolve method 'setName' in 'Person'

Please guide me that where I am making a mistake. Thank you!

Comment: If class `Person` is self-written: make the constructor `public`. If it is not self-written: look at the documentation, see if it has a factory method or builder.

Comment: Looks like you imported `android.app.Person` while you wanted to import `Person` in your app's namespace.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of the `Person` class. Besides that, what is the exact import that you're using? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: I still don't see the definition of the `Person` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo I am not getting your point. Can you please explain what you are asking?

Comment: You're using in your code a `Person` class. Like here `Person person = new Person();`. How is this class defined?

Comment: @AlexMamo Let me share the link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Person               As I know Person is a built-in class and we have to just import `android.app.Person` and by making an object we use. I also share the link of where I saw this thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561497/how-to-add-new-data-in-firebase-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the following error:

> 'Person()' has private access in 'android.app.Person'

Because there is no way you can create a new instance of the `Person` class. Why? because the constructor of the class is private:

```
private Person() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

So in order to write an object in the Realtime Database, the class should contain a public no-argument constructor. That being said, to solve this issue,  you have to create your own Person class. At a minimum, it should look like this:

```
class Person {
    String name;
}
```

In which the constructor is provided by the JVM, or if you want to use encapsulation:

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person() {} //

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. this helps me a lot to understand. @Alex Mamo

Comment: You're very welcome, Iqra. So Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: I have just basic knowledge of android development and I have to create my final year project. So can you please help me out if I get stuck somewhere? @Alex Mamo

Comment: If you post questions, here on Stackoverflow, why not?

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding this particular question?

Comment: Ok I will post it on Stackoverflow. And this question is clear to me. Thank You! @Alex Mamo